# Using plotly's subplot function with a shared legend, have each group appear only once in the legend

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the following figure:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4), col2 = rnorm(12), col3 = runif(12), col4 = rep(c("Fred", "Bob"), each = 6))
df1_list <- split(df1, df1$col1)
colors <- setNames(c('red', 'blue'), c("Fred", "Bob"))
lapply(df1_list, function (arg1) {
  plotly::plot_ly(arg1, x = ~col2, y = ~col3, color = ~col4, colors = colors) %>%
    layout(showlegend = T)
}) %>%
  subplot()
```

The legend shows each person's name twice. Is there an efficient, programmatic way to display each name only once in the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a solution with a detour via ggplot2. Hope this helps for your purpose.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4), col2 = rnorm(12), col3 = runif(12), col4 = rep(c("Fred", "Bob"), each = 6))

p <- ggplot(df1, aes(col2, col3)) + geom_point(aes(color = col4)) + facet_wrap("col1")

plotly::ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: This is great - thanks